# How can I check the timestamp of a remote commit without cloning the repository?

Tags: git

There is a Git sub-command called `ls-remote` which allows listing of all the branches and commit hashes of the leaf node/tip of each branch.

How can I also query the timestamp of those commits, or other related information of the commit, **without cloning the repo locally**? (or, is there no way to do this without cloning the repo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite what you want but using [`git clone --depth=1`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---depthltdepthgt) you could clone only a single commit without the whole history.

Other than that there are not built-in capabilities to read metadata directly from a remote repository.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I guess the next step for me would be to go create a feature request, if it doesn't exist already.